# Is it possible to create fileIO within a program?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a bunch of code that has now evolved into a fully functioning console based (mostly) game. I'm now curious that if I want to implement an Input/Output function do I have to create it in a different file or can I put it in the same class as my code. For instance, an example my lecturer has given for writing a fileIO for saving names is the following:

```
import java.io.*;

class savenames
{
   public static void main(String[] params) throws IOException 
   {
       PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("mydata.txt"));

       // Create an array with some sample names to store
       String [] names = {"Paul", "Jo", "Mo"};

       // Store the names from the array in the file, one name per line    
       for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
       {
               outputStream.println(names[i]);
       }  
       outputStream.close();
       System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

This accompanies the following code (in a different file):

```
import java.io.*;

class readnames
{
   public static void main(String[] params) throws IOException 
   {
       BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mydata.txt"));
       String [] names = new String[3];
       System.out.println("The names in the file mydata.txt are:");

       for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
       {
           names[i] = inStream.readLine();
           System.out.println(names[i]);
       }
       inStream.close();
       System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

I was just wondering if it would be possible do the two things in the same file, as my code has many different methods and I'm not sure how to make a separate method to do this. Thanks.

EDIT: Perhaps I can modify this question to make it a little better.

I have the following main method in my boardgame:

```
class newminip
{
   public static void main (String[] params) throws IOException
   { 
       numberPlayers();
       int diceroll = dicethrow(6);
       int[] scorep1 = scorearrayp1();
       questions(diceroll, scorep1);
       sort(scorep1);
       System.exit(0);
   }  

   .... insert code here ....

   public static void exitmethod(int[] scorep1)
   {
      sort(scorep1);
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Player " + (i+1) + " scored " + scorep1[i] + "");
      }
      System.exit(0);
   }

} //END class
```

And I want something that will save the scores into a new text file. I hope this had made it a tiny bit clearer.

Comment: Better to do it in a different Java file, but not in a main or static method. You will want to learn about OOPs and Java first.

Comment: At the moment we're focusing on procedural programming as opposed to OOP which we'll be doing next semmester. Is learning up on OOPs important for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do it in one file. I have created a new class for it:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileIO {

    public static String[] readStringsFromFile(final String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        //Use ArrayList since you don't know how many lines there are in the file
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        String line;
        //Read until you reach the end of the file
        while ((line = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        inStream.close();

        //Convert it back to a string array
        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    }

    public static void writeStringsToFile(String[] lines, final String filename) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            outputStream.println(lines[i]);
        }
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //To test the methods:
        //Create an array to write to the file
        String[] linesToWrite = {"firstLine", "secondLine", "thirdLine"};
        try {
            //Write the strings to a file named "testfile.txt"
            writeStringsToFile(linesToWrite, "testfile.txt");

            //Read all lines of a file named "testfile.txt"
            String[] readLines = readStringsFromFile("testfile.txt");

            //Print out the read lines
            for (String line : readLines) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error msg");
        }
    }
}
```

The main method in this case is just to test, you can remove it and  copy the two other methods to your class. This is probably not the best or most efficient way to do file io but in your case this should do the job (:
EDIT:
So if you just need to read an write integers to a file you could use something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileIO {

    public static Integer[] readIntegersFromFile(final String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        //Use ArrayList since you don't know how many lines there are in the file
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        String line;
        //Read until you reach the end of the file
        while ((line = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            //Parse integers form read string values
            integers.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
        }
        inStream.close();

        return integers.toArray(new Integer[integers.size()]);
    }

    public static void writeIntegersToFile(Integer[] lines, final String filename) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            outputStream.println(lines[i]);
        }
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //To test the methods:
        //Create an array to write to the file
        Integer[] linesToWrite = {1, 100, 15};
        try {
            //Write the strings to a file named "testfile.txt"
            writeStringsToFile(linesToWrite, "testfile.txt");

            //Read all lines of a file named "testfile.txt"
            Integer[] readLines = readStringsFromFile("testfile.txt");

            //Print out the read lines
            for (int line : readLines) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error msg");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very good, almost exactly what I'm looking to replicate - so thank you. Just out of curiousity, I want to read and save an array of numbers from my actual program so am I correct in thinking that I can do this by changing `String` to `int` in the class?

Comment: @Overclock It won't be enough because the readLine() method will always return a string so you could use something like Integer.parseInt() but if you need it I can add it to my answer :)

Comment: If you could add something like that to your answer I would be eternally grateful. Also there's another matter of how I would invoke this class within the same file as my boardgame. What would I do when compiling in order to get the file to save?

Comment: @Overclock I have updated the answer. If it is what you were looking for please accept it . You could add it as a private class but i recommend adding another file for the class or just copy the methods to your current main class

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Java file with the code from both main methods and remove the `System.exit(0);` as you don't need it.  This way one program will do both.  I suggest you write the file before attempting to read it.

Putting it all in one program make the use of the file rather redundant however, in which case you can just print the array.